# Insert in array in selected order changed on save

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, select

I have a problem. I have a small script where I am adding Country for some tv show in the database.

I have table *country* with id, name and flag fields.

There I have

1. 1 - USA - usa.png
2. 2 - UK - uk.png

etc

Then i have this:

```
<select name="drzava[]" class="ui fluid search dropdown full" id="drzava" multiple="">
<?php
if(isset($value['drzava'])) {
    foreach ($drzava as $key => $value_d) {
        $niz = explode(",", $value['drzava']);
        $selected = "";
        if (in_array($value_d['id'],$niz)) {
            $selected="selected";
        }
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value_d['id'];?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $value_d['drzava'];?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

That $drzava use

```
public function listoftvshowdrzava() {
  $db = APP::getInstance('database');
  $stm = $db -> query("SELECT `id` , `name`, `flag` FROM `country`");
  $rez2 = $stm -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $basket = APP::getInstance('Basket');
  $basket->set('listtvshowdrzava',$rez2);
  return $rez2;
}
```

So my problem is when I for some tv show add USA than the UK, it write 1,2 in the tv show. And that's ok. But when I enter the first UK, the US. It anyway inserts 1,2. Not 2,1 as I want. Where I making mistake. I try so many things, but no one will work.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `$value` coming from? What does it look like?

Comment: Please post your table structure for TV Shows. Are you saving comma separated strings into your DB? If so, you really need to refactor to save each entry as a row. It will save you a world of trouble.

Comment: $value['drzava'] comeing from database. Thats work fine. It have id's of countries. There is 1,2 (id's for countryes). Thats work. My problem is when i add manually in database 2,1 but when i load page or edit they change to 1,2. @waterloomatt

Comment: @waterloomatt yes i save in comma separated strings in db. That works. But somewhere in select is problem. If i select first 2 then 1, they anyway change it to 1,2 not 2,1...

Comment: `yes i save in comma separated strings in db. That works.`. No, it doesn't. Normalize your DB. Also, please post all your code including your INSERT/UPDATE statements. Your question is a bit too hard to understand, can you rephrase it?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5166) That is exactly my problem. Order in semantic ui multiselect. But it doesn't work. @waterloomatt